# is there any alternative to 'Wait Until Page Does Not Contain Element' keyword?

Tags: javascript, robotframework

I am currently using the `Wait Until Page Does Not Contain Element` to wait for a UI Overlay to disappear before I interact with the underlying elements. It works but waits for complete 30 seconds even if the UI Overlay disappears in initial 1-2 seconds. Thsi results in long execution time for the complete workflow.

Have tried to use `Element Should Be Visible`, `Wait Until Element Is Enabled` & other keywords as a workaround to verify if the underlying elements (textbox or links) can be worked with but it fails most of the time as probably the elements under the UI overlay are still enabled / visible. Is there any workaround I can use by creating my own custom keyword or using javascript ?

Comment: This may be of some help - https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary/issues/1364